# Are __func__ and __FUNCTION__ pointers persistent?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

For gcc projects, are the pointers returned by `__FUNCTION__`, `__FILE__` and `__func__` guaranteed to point to persistent memory?  (That is, can I safely deference the pointers in the scope of another function?)   I know that `__func__` is supposed to act like a `const char __func__ = "filename"` at the beginning of the function, which implies that "filename" points to something in the data segment of the program, and that the pointer should therefore be valid outside of the function.   The others are strings, which again, should create entries in the data section.   That being said, I don't trust it, and I'm wondering if someone here can confirm whether the assumption is correct.

For example:

```
struct debugLog_t {
      const char * func;
      const char * file;
      const char * function;
      uint32_t     line;
      int          val;
} log;

struct debugLog_t someLog = {};

someFunc() {
      // create debug log:
      if (x) {
           //uh oh... 
           someLog.func = __func__;
           someLog.function = __FUNCTION__;
           someLog.file = __FILE__;
           someLog.line = line;
           someLog.val = val;
      }
}

void dumpSomeLog() {
      printf("%s(%s) -- %s.%d: error val is x\n", 
             someLog.function, someLog.func, someLog.file, someLog.line,
             someLog.val);
}
```

I want to do this to reduce memory/processing time of recording debug logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't call that *persistent* memory (read wikipage on [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science))) but read only memory (or section) in the [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment).

And yes, `__func__`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__FILE__` go there (as `static const char[]` arrays); like literal strings.

Notice that two occurrences of a literal string like `"ab"` may or not be compiled into the same addresses (likewise, `"bc"` can or not be equal to pointer `"abc"+1`). Likewise for two occurrences of `__FILE__`; however, within the *same* function, all occurrences of `__func__` should have the same address.

With GCC (at least at `-O1` optimization) literal constant strings of the same content share the same location. I would even believe that in function `foo` the `__func__` and `"foo"` might share the same address (but with GCC they don't, even at `-O2`). You could check by compiling with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O1` and look at the generated `*.s` assembler file.

For example:

```
 const char*f(int x) { 
   if (x==0) return "f";
   if (x>0) return  __func__;
   return __FUNCTION__;
 }
```

gets compiled with `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S` (using GCC 7 on Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64) as

```
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
 .LC0:
    .string "f"
    .text
    .globl  f
    .type   f, @function
 f:
 .LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
 # f.c:2:   if (x==0) return "f";
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax    #, <retval>
    testl   %edi, %edi  # x
    je  .L1 #,
 # f.c:3:   if (x>0) return  __func__;
    testl   %edi, %edi  # x
 # f.c:4:   return __FUNCTION__;
    leaq    __func__.1795(%rip), %rax   #, tmp94
    leaq    __FUNCTION__.1796(%rip), %rdx   #, tmp95
    cmovle  %rdx, %rax  # tmp94,, tmp95, <retval>
 .L1:
 # f.c:5: }
    rep ret
    .cfi_endproc
 .LFE0:
    .size   f, .-f
    .section    .rodata
    .type   __FUNCTION__.1796, @object
    .size   __FUNCTION__.1796, 2
 __FUNCTION__.1796:
    .string "f"
    .type   __func__.1795, @object
    .size   __func__.1795, 2
 __func__.1795:
    .string "f"
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 7.2.0-8) 7.2.0"
```

Even with `-Os` or `-O3` I'm getting three different locations in the code segment.

However [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) 5 with `-O3` (or even `-O1`) merge all three `"f"`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__` by putting them at the same location (and optimize the test by removing it):

```
    .type   f,@function
f:                                      # @f
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    movl    $.L.str, %eax
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   f, .Lfunc_end0-f
    .cfi_endproc
                                        # -- End function
    .type   .L.str,@object          # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz  "f"
    .size   .L.str, 2
```

So the pointers you care about are pointers to `static const char[]` in the code segment but you should not always expect that `__func__` has the same address than  `__FUNCTION__` (even if that could be).

Comment: But where would that go? Inside each function or at translation unit level?

Comment: These are not strings literals, actually. But constant arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are. These constants actually act like `static` declarations. From the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html), `__func__` acts as though the function begins with

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
```

and `__FUNCTION__` is basically the same.

Comment: Moreover, `__func__` is defined that way by [C Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2p1)

Answer (score 1):

According to C2011, the `__FILE__` macro expands to

> The presumed name of the current source file (***a character string literal***).

([C2011 6.10.8.1/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8.1p1); emphasis added)

Therefore, yes, you can assign that to a pointer variable, and expect to be able to safely dereference it for the lifetime of the program.

The standard also specifies the form for `__func__`, which is effectively an implicit *variable*, not a macro:

> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the
>   translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each
>   function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared [...].

([C2011, 6.4.2.2/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2p1))

In this case, then, the identifier designates an array of `const char` with static storage duration.  In this case, too, it is safe to record a pointer to this and dereference at an arbitrary time thereafter in the program run.

As an extension and backwards-compatibility provision, GCC also provides `__FUNCTION__` as an alias for `__func__`, so the same answer applies to the former as applies to the latter: yes, the strings they reference reside in persistent memory, which you can safely access from another function.

Comment: `__FILE__` is required to expand to a string literal (and so are `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`), see 6.10.8.1.  `__FUNCTION__` is a GCC extension, but IIRC it has always been treated more-or-less the same as `__func__`.

Comment: Thank you, @zwol.  I don't know how I overlooked that -- I *did* look for it.  Updated.